# how to pass null values to url.content() and show result

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display images using `url.content()` in MVC using an `img` tag. I succeeded, but it displays an 'argument exception' error when there are some empty images, so I want to show null images also. Here is my code.

```html
<img src="@Url.Content(item.image)" alt="Image" height="50" width="50"  class="img-circle img-responsive" />
```

It succeeds when it has value but I want empty images also.

Comment: Just wrap the `img` tag in an `if` condition, eg `if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(item.image))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming "empty images" as HTTP 404 requests, you can do the following

```
<img src="@Url.Content(item.image ?? "~/empty-image.jpg")" alt="Image" height="50" width="50"  class="img-circle img-responsive" />
```

And substitute "~/empty-image.jpg" with a valid URL pointing to an appropriate image hosted on your website.

Otherwise, as other mentioned, just wrap your code into an **if-statement** using [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.